# How to react correctly after a complete refresh (f5 or any other similar way) of the application

Tags: angular, web-applications

I am a bit new in web application development and I am faced with the problem of when the user through f5 or any other way does a full reload of the application. I am specifically using Angular 2-4 but this should be a common theme in the development no matter what technology is used.
 The problem is that they lose the values of the variables that are in the components, services (Angular) and controllers in general. So, how to proceed and protect yourself in this case?
I have seen two possible variants:

- he first is to store the values in the local storage
- the other is to receive values through routing in such a way that when the url is refreshed it is the same and therefore the values are taken. This is more restricted and more difficult to maintain and adapt.

Then someone with more experience could explain and help me with good practices and the correct way to handle this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would use a service that queues and periodically saves changes to [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).  Here is a quick draft (untested code):

```
export class StateService {
  public saved = true;
  private saveThreadID:number;

  constructor(){
    // save changes every 60 seconds
    this.saveThreadID = setInterval(()=>this.saveChanges(),60000);
  }
  // Registers changes that will be saved later
  public queueChanges(changes:Array<{key:string, value:any}>){
    this.unsavedChanges.push(...changes);
    this.saved = false;
  }
  // Array of changes queued for saving
  private unsavedChanges:Array<{key:string,value:any}> = [];

  // Writes all unsaved changes to SessionStorage
  private saveChanges(){
    for(let change of this.unsavedChanges){
      window.sessionStorage.setItem(change.key, JSON.parse(change.value));
    }
    this.unsavedChanges.splice(0); // empty array
    this.saved = true;
  }
}
```

1. Inject the service in all components with important state data. When the user makes a change you want to keep, call the service's `queueChanges`
2. The `saveChanges` routine will persist changes at regular interval (this is to prevent constantly writing to session storage, which is a slow operation)
3. At this point, changes are saved every 60 seconds.  You can go further still. For instance, you can add a [CanDeactivate Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes) to your routes that will ask the user whether she wants to save changes if the guard notices that `StateService.saved === false`.

You can get a lot fancier, but I would think along these lines if I had important data to preserve.